# Albedo mask works properly but when plugged into bump its like it has no mask at all

Tags: materials, masking

[[image: raw albedo preview][1]]

[image: bump output preview]

[image: node setup]

I have an image, with black and white to mask out the noise for bump. but when i go to plug the mask into a mix as the factor, i get noise everywhere in the bump output, but what i want in the albedo, despite the fact that the mix which i was viewing is plugged directly into the bump node with no alterations along the way. I tried having a raw color on the bottom of the mix, instead of the white part of the image, but to no avail.

Comment: If the thing mask is anything other than pure black and pure white it won't have the hard cutoff you're wanting.  You can perhaps do some math in the node editor to convert it.

Comment: it is pure black and white though. the first image shows that the raw albedo mask works, but when i plug that albedo output into the bump, it stops working

Comment: I see.  Instead of mixing can you use the mask as the strength input of the bump node?